# Call a method in an instance that a calling class implements - but is otherwise unrelated

Tags: python, class, methods

Say I have this file structure:

- project
- - gui
- - - *gui.py*
- - - widgets
- - - - *base_widg.py*
- - midi
- - - *main.py*

*main.py* contains a class called **Engine**, and a method inside that, called **midi_out**

*base_widg.py* contains a class called  **BaseWidg**

*gui.py* is the file that I run when I want to test the entire program, and implements both an instance of the **Engine** class in *main.py* and an instance of the **BaseWidg** class in *base_widg.py*

There is a method inside **BaseWidg** that needs to call the **midi_out** function in the implemented instance of **Engine**

#### EDIT

in the **init** function of **Engine**:

```
self.midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
```

This is important because many of the other methods need this declaration, including **midi_out**, because:

```
def midi_out(self, note, vel, state):
    # figure out what channel is (irrelevant)
    self.midiout.send_message([channel, note, vel)
```

Unfortunately this tends to suggest to me I cannot use @staticmethod...

What is the most pythonic and efficient way to do this? Do I need to change the structure of my program?

Potentially irrelevant: I am using python 2.7, pygtk 2 and python_rtmidi.

Comment: Using staticmethod at midi_out definition.
And use statement Engine.midi_out() inside BaseWidg

Comment: For some reason I forgot to mention something really important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have the constructor of **BaseWidg** take an instance of **Engine** and store it as an instance variable.  Then you can just call the `midi_out()` method of that instance of **Engine** from within **BaseWidg**.

Comment: That's definitely one option. I was hoping python might have something fancy up its sleeve, but I'll do what works for now, thanks for your help!

Comment: Np. This approach is actually pretty commonly used.  It's a kind of [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection).

Comment: So it's genuinely the best, most pythonic way to do this? Excellent! Thank you!